# WPF change mouse cursor to Hand when Grab

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been looking for a solution to this problem:
When draging a contro, how to change the mouse corsur to Hand?
Not regular mouse cursor with the little icon under it, but to a hand.
All I can find is changing when hovering in drag mode over a specific control, not all the drag time.
Any idea would be great, thanks.

Comment: What about directly setting `Mouse.OverrideCursor` then set it back after the drag ends?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by control, you mean a `Thumb`, such as:

```
<Canvas>
    <Thumb Cursor="Hand Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="30" Height="30" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
</Canvas>
```

in which

```
    private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {  
        Thumb thumb = (Thumb)sender;
        Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
    }
```

You can simply add `Cursor="Hand"` to the `<Thumb .../>` and it will work.